# Method vs Functions, and other questions

Tags: javascript, function, methods

With respect to JS, what's the difference between the two? I know methods are associated with objects, but am confused what's the purpose of functions? How does the syntax of each of them differ?

Also, what's the difference between these 2 syntax'es:

```
var myFirstFunc = function(param) {
    //Do something
};
```

and

```
function myFirstFunc(param) {
    //Do something
};
```

Also, I saw somewhere that we need to do something like this before using a function:

```
obj.myFirstFunc = myFirstFunc;
obj.myFirstFunc("param");
```

Why is the first line required, and what does it do?

Sorry if these are basic questions, but I'm starting with JS and am confused.

EDIT: For the last bit of code, this is what I'm talking about:

```
// here we define our method using "this", before we even introduce bob
var setAge = function (newAge) {
  this.age = newAge;
};
// now we make bob
var bob = new Object();
bob.age = 30;
// and down here we just use the method we already made
bob.setAge = setAge;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: Look for "Function declaration vs function expression".

Comment: Where did you see that last part? There's no reason to do that, unless `obj.myFirstFunc` is undefined and needs to be a reference to `myFirstFunc`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Codecademy. I can't remember the exercise where it was though. Found the code, editing OP now.

Comment: In answer to the last question (so it will stop bugging me)  they have defined a function and assigned it to `myFirstFunc`.  They also have a variable `obj` which is a class with the property `myFirstFunc`.  They are copying the function from the local variable to the object.  The copy is not required to call the function from the local variable (`myFirstFunc("param");`).  The copy is required if you want to call the function from the object (`obj.myFirstFunc("param");`), especially where the local variable is out of scope.

Answer (score 65):

To answer your title question as to what is the difference between a 'function' and a 'method'.

It's semantics and has to do with what you are trying to express.

In JavaScript every function is an object. An object is a collection of key:value pairs. If a value is a primitive (number, string, boolean), or another object, the value is considered a property. If a value is a function, it is called a 'method'.

Within the scope of an object, a function is referred to as a method of that object. It is invoked from the object namespace `MyObj.theMethod().` Since we said that a function is an object, a function within a function can be considered a method of that function.

You could say things like “I am going to use the save **method** of my object.” And "This save method accepts a **function** as a parameter.” But you generally wouldn't say that a function accepts a method as a parameter.

Btw, the book *JavaScript Patterns* by [Stoyan Stefanov](http://www.phpied.com/publishing-5-books-this-year/) covers your questions in detail, and I highly recommend it if you really want to understand the language. Here's a quote from the book on this subject:

> So it could happen that a function A, being an object, has properties and methods, one of which happens to be another function B. Then B can accept a function C as an argument and, when executed, can return another function D.

Comment: According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39263543/5238583), just saying `If a value is a function, it is called a 'method'.`  seems not accurate?

Comment: @TinaChen you are right this answer reflects the state of javascript in 2013 and needs to be updated for ES6. Frankly the whole thing is not that important. Call it whatever you want: function/method. A function is usually in the top level (global) namespace, a method belongs to a class/object namespace and has to be called with that receiver.

Comment: primitive is number, string, boolean

Answer (score 36):

There is a slight difference -

Method : Method is a function when object is associated with it.

```
var obj = {
name : "John snow",
work : function someFun(paramA, paramB) {
    // some code..
}
```

Function : When no object is associated with it , it comes to function.

```
function fun(param1, param2){
// some code...
}
```

Comment: Great, simple answer.

Answer (score 24):

Many answers are saying something along the lines that a *method* is what a function is called when it is defined on an object.

While this is often true in the way the word is used when people talk about JavaScript or object oriented programming in general (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/155655/10367549)), it is worth noting that **in ES6 the term *method* has taken on a very specific meaning** (see section [14.3 Method Definitions](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-method-definitions) of the specs).

---

## Method Definitions

A *method* (in the strict sense) is a function that was defined through the concise method syntax in an object literal or as a class method in a class declaration / expression:

```
// In object literals:
const obj = {
    method() {}
};

// In class declarations:
class MyClass {
    method() {}
}
```

---

## Method Specificities

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39263543/10367549) gives a good overview about the specificities of *methods* (in the strict sense), namely:

1. methods get assigned an internal `[[HomeObject]]` property which allows them to use `super`.
2. methods are not created with a `prototype` property and they don't have an internal `[[Construct]]` method which means that they cannot be called with `new`.
3. the name of a method does not become a binding in the method's scope.

Below are some examples illustrating how methods (in the strict sense) differ from functions defined on objects through function expressions:

#### Example 1

```js
const obj = {
    method() {
        super.test;         // All good!
    },
    ordinaryFunction: function ordinaryFunction() {
        super.test;         // SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here
    }
};
```

#### Example 2

```js
const obj = {
    method() {},
    ordinaryFunction: function ordinaryFunction() {}
};

console.log( obj.ordinaryFunction.hasOwnProperty( 'prototype' ) );  // true
console.log( obj.method.hasOwnProperty( 'prototype' ) );            // false

new obj.ordinaryFunction();     // All good !
new obj.method();               // TypeError: obj.method is not a constructor
```

#### Example 3

```js
const obj = {
    method() {
        console.log( method );
    },
    ordinaryFunction: function ordinaryFunction() {
        console.log( ordinaryFunction );
    }
};

obj.ordinaryFunction()  // All good!
obj.method()            // ReferenceError: method is not defined
```

Comment: Excellent modern answer

Answer (score 2):

A method is a property of an object whose value is a function. Methods are called on objects in the following format: object.method().

//this is an object named developer

```
 const developer = {
  name: 'Andrew',
  sayHello: function () {
    console.log('Hi there!');
  },
  favoriteLanguage: function (language) {
    console.log(`My favorite programming language is ${language}`);
  }
};
```

// favoriteLanguage: and sayHello: and name: all of them are proprieties in the object named developer

now lets say you needed to call favoriteLanguage propriety witch is a function inside the object..

you call it this way

```
developer.favoriteLanguage('JavaScript');

// My favorite programming language is JavaScript'
```

so what we name this:  developer.favoriteLanguage('JavaScript'); 
its not a function its not an object? what it is? its a method

Answer (score 1):

Your first line, is creating an object that references a function. You would reference it like this:

```
myFirstFunc(param);
```

But you can pass it to another function since it will return the function like so:

```
function mySecondFunction(func_param){}
mySecondFunction(myFirstFunc);
```

The second line just creates a function called `myFirstFunc` which would be referenced like this:

```
myFirstFunc(param);
```

And is limited in scope depending on where it is declared, if it is declared outside of any other function it belongs to the global scope. However you can declare a function inside another function. The scope of that function is then limited to the function its declared inside of.

```
function functionOne(){
    function functionTwo(){}; //only accessed via the functionOne scope!
}
```

Your final examples are creating instances of functions that are then referenced though an object parameter. So this:

```
function myFirstFunc(param){};

obj.myFirst = myFirstFunc(); //not right!
obj.myFirst = new myFirstFunc(); //right!

obj.myFirst('something here'); //now calling the function
```

Says that you have an object that references an instance of a function. The key here is that if the function changes the *reference* you stored in `obj.myFirst` will not be changed.

While @kevin is basically right there is only functions in JS you can create functions that are much more like methods then functions, take this for example:

```
function player(){

    this.stats = {
        health: 0,
        mana: 0,

        get : function(){
            return this;
        },

        set : function( stats ){
            this.health = stats.health;
            this.mana = stats.mana;
        }  
}
```

You could then call `player.stats.get()` and it would return to you the value of `heath`, and `mana`. So I would consider `get` and `set` in this instance to be methods of the `player.stats` object.

Comment: That actually helps. I'll look up more on this and ask further if I have doubts

Comment: You comment that it cannot be passed as a parameter is not true.

Answer (score 1):

A function executes a list of statements example:

```
 function add() { 
     var a = 2; 
     var b = 3;
     var c = a + b;
     return c;
 }
```

1) A method is a function that is applied to an object example:

```
 var message = "Hello world!";
 var x = message.toUpperCase(); // .toUpperCase() is a built in function
```

2) Creating a method using an object constructor. Once the method belongs to the object you can apply it to that object. example:

```
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
    this.name = function() {return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;};
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.fullName(); // using the 
method
```

Definition of  a method: A method is a property of an object that is a function. Methods are defined the way normal functions are defined, except that they have to be assigned as the property of an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myFirstFunc = function(param) {
    //Do something
};
```

and

```
function myFirstFunc(param) {
    //Do something
};
```

are (almost) identical. The second is (usually) just shorthand. However, as this jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/cu2Sy/) shows, `function myFirstFunc` will cause the function to be defined as soon as the enclosing scope is entered, whereas `myFirstFunc = function` will only create it once execution reaches that line.

As for methods, they have a `this` argument, which is the current object, so:

```
var obj = {};
obj.func = function( ) {
    // here, "this" is obj
    this.test = 2;
}
console.log( obj.test ); // undefined
obj.func( );
console.log( obj.test ); // 2
```

The exact syntax you showed is because you can also do this:

```
function abc( ) {
    this.test = 2;
}
var obj = {};
obj.func = abc;
obj.func( ); // sets obj.test to 2
```

but you shouldn't without good reason.

Comment: Not my downvote, but likely because the first is a *FunctionExpression*, the second is a *FunctionDeclaration*, the difference is when they are created. The first is when that line of code is executed, the second is created before any code is executed.

Comment: @user2059238: I can't think of a simple good reason, but it could be needed in a library function which has a callback (the function can be passed as a parameter), or if you have two possible behaviours to choose between (`obj.doYourThing = isAngel ? myGoodFunc : myBadFunc`), although the second is rather silly. It also lets you define private functions which are also public if you're using closures (but that only gives any benefit if you're also using an optimising compiler).

Comment: yes, because you need to set it to something! My point is that you should use `bob.setAge = function(){whatever}` rather than `function blah(){whatever};bob.setAge=blah;`. The latter is bad because it pollutes the scope with variables, and leaves a function which only makes sense when applied to an object (and if you used `this` in the function, is only *safe* when applied to an object)

Answer (score 0):

[ecma document](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-method)

> 4.3.31method : 
>   function that is the value of a property
>
> NOTE When a function is called as a method of an object, the object is
>   passed to the function as its this value.

It is very clear: when you call a function if it implicitly has a `this` (**to point an object**) and if you can't call the function without an object, **the function** deserves to name as **method**.