# super keyword unexpected here

Tags: ecmascript-6, super

According to ES6 shorthand initialiser, following 2 methods are same:

### In ES5

```
var person = {
  name: "Person",
  greet: function() {
     return "Hello " + this.name;
  }
};
```

### In ES6

```
var person = {
  name: "Person",
  greet() {
     return "Hello " + this.name;
  }
};
```

Do the ES6 way is in anyway different from the previous way? If not then using "super" inside them should be also treated as equal, which doesn't hold true, please see below two variaiton:

### Below works

```
let person = {
  greet(){
   super.greet(); 
  }
};

Object.setPrototypeOf(person, {
  greet: function(){ console.log("Prototype method"); }
});

person.greet();
```

### Below fails

```
let person = {
  greet: function(){
   super.greet(); // Throw error: Uncaught SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here
  }
};

Object.setPrototypeOf(person, {
  greet: function(){ console.log("Prototype method"); }
});

person.greet();
```

---

The only difference in above 2 examples is the way we declare method greet in person object, which should be same. So, why do we get error?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> So, why do we get error?

Because `super` is only valid inside [**methods**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-method-definitions). `greet: function() {}` is a "normal" property/function, not a method, because it doesn't follow the method syntax.

The differences between a method and a normal function definition are:

- Methods have a "HomeObject" which is what allows them to use `super`.
- Methods are not constructable, i.e. they cannot be called with `new`.
- The name of a method doesn't become a binding in the method's scope (unlike named function expressions).

Comment: Regarding "Methods are not constructable, i.e. they cannot be called with new.", I am able to create new object using new : http://www.es6fiddle.net/iskh3nhl/

Comment: es6fiddle seems to compile the code to ES5. If you post the code into the browser console (assuming your browser supports ES6), you will get `Uncaught TypeError: person.greet is not a constructor(…)`.

Comment: Can you suggest any best book or other learning source for ES6? Which talks about such depth of each new features in ES6?

Comment: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS is the best I know. Very technical. Not sure if it talks about that though.

Comment: @FelixKling In ES6, greet(){} seems to be a shorthand expression for greet: function(){}.  So why would the super keyword still work differently between those two?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15285702/5238583 But this answer says that `method` is just function value in object ?

Comment: In [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions), there seems no such definition. Sorry for that I cannot quite understand the Specification. I have the same doubt with @whales

Comment: @Tina: That answer is from 2013, so before ES2015 was released. Until then, we just informally called functions that are properties of objects "methods". *"In MDN, there seems no such definition."* What do you mean? The page you linked shows exactly what methods are (syntax-wise). I can update the page if that's helpful. A simple way to realize that these two are different is: `var obj = {foo: function() {}, bar() {}}; new obj.foo(); new obj.bar();` One works, the other doesn't. So it's not *just* a shorthand. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I've moved my doubt to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165046/why-homeobject-is-different-in-shorthand-syntax-of-method) and got an answer. Now I'm fully understand shorthand syntax(method) is not just a shorter function syntax in ES2015. (And also learned how to read specification...)

Answer (score 1):

I got here from searching the V8 error message ['super' keyword unexpected here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/12.2.196/src/common/message-template.h#L636C24-L636C54). Here are the possible reasons for the error:

- `super.prop` can only be used in the body of a concise method (`foo() {}`, `*foo() {}`, `async foo() {}`, or `async *foo() {}`), accessor (`get foo() {}`, `set foo() {}`, `static get foo(val) {}`, or `static set foo(val) {}`), or `constructor() {}` ([parser-base.h](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/12.2.196/src/parsing/parser-base.h#L3811-L3812)).

  - You can’t access `super` from an ordinary function `foo: function() {}` or arrow function `foo: () => {}`. You must to convert it to a concise function `foo() {}`.
- `super()` call can only be inside a `constructor() {}` of a derived class ([parser-base.h](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/12.2.196/src/parsing/parser-base.h#L3833)).

  - If you want some method `foo()` to call the superclass’s `foo()`, then you call `foo() {super.foo()}`, not `foo() {super()}`.
  - Make sure that the `class` `extends` some other class.

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling of constructor
This error can also occur , If you have a spelling mistake .