# Why [[HomeObject]] is different in shorthand syntax of method?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, super

This question is derived from [super keyword unexpected here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263358/super-keyword-unexpected-here)

The accepted answer says:

> Because super is only valid inside methods.

But in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions), it seems these two are both methods:

```
let person = {
    greeting() {
        return "Hello";
    }
};

let friend = {
    // shorter syntax for method?
    greeting() {
        return super.greeting() + ", hi!";
    }

//  method?
//  greeting: function() {
//      return super.greeting() + ", hi!"; // Throw error: Uncaught SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here
//  }

};

Object.setPrototypeOf(friend, person);
console.log(friend.greeting());
```

In [understanding es6](https://github.com/nzakas/understandinges6/blob/master/manuscript/04-Objects.md#a-formal-method-definition), Nacholas says:

> Attempting to use `super` outside of concise methods results in a syntax error
>
> `Methods` were just object properties that contained functions instead of data.
>
> Any reference to `super` uses the [[HomeObject]] to determine what to do.
> The first step is to call Object.getPrototypeOf() on the [[HomeObject]] to retrieve a reference to the prototype.
> Then, the prototype is searched for a function with the same name. Last, the this binding is set and the method is called.

So it seems [[HomeObject]] is different in shorthand syntax of method? I'm curious why?

Comment: Can you show the containing context for your two code blocks?  What are these inside of?   `greet: function() {}` that's just a property declaration on a normal object is probably not technically a "method" as far as `super` is concerned.  It's just a plain property.  In all cases, why not just use the `class` syntax and avoid the whole issue.  You're already requiring `super` to be available so it's not like you can't count on `class`.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00, 1. code blocks has completed. 2. in MDN, `greet: function() {}` seems satisfy `method` definition? That's what confusing me. 3. `class` syntax is another topic, I am just watching the book and curious about `super` behavior.

Comment: Well, `super()` is designed for use with `class`.  If that's where you use it, then you have none of these puzzles to figure out.

Comment: In [MDN super #"Using super.prop in object literals"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super), there is also an example of using `super` in the object initializer / literal notation

Comment: And notice that those object literal examples ONLY use the shortcut method syntax.  It appears there's something special about that syntax.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, that's what I want to ask: what's special about this syntax??This is not documented. BTW, I'll avoid to use `super` in object literal, thanks.

Comment: I don't have the energy right now to try to follow the complex web of syntax in the EMCASCript specification, but it is the [`MakeMethod()` call](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-definemethod) that sets `[[HomeObject]]` and then allows the use of `super`.  You'd have to follow the chain of syntax definitions to find out exactly what syntax does and doesn't lead to `MakeMethod()` getting called or not called.  MDN is not the documentation source - the EMCAScript specification is the source.

Comment: It looks like it's here: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer.  Only the shortcut syntax is a [MethodDefinition](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-method-definitions) (which has super capabilities).  The regular property syntax is just a property, not a "method" in the way that Javascript defines and initializes what it calls a "method".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, MDN is not official Javascript documentation.  While it's often helpful, it's not the definitive source for anything related to the language.  That official specification would be in the [ECMAScript specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0).  That's where the Javascript grammar is defined.

In that document, there is something called a [MethodDefinition](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-method-definitions).  There are several syntaxes that can be used for a method definition.  The `greeting() {}` syntax is one such syntax that can be used for a MethodDefinition.  The typical object literal property definition of `propName: function() {}` is not.  Here's how it is defined:

[image]

Then, to see what a `MethodDefinition` is, you go to [section 14.3.8](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-definemethod) where it documents the steps for a `MethodDefinition` as follows:

[image]

In Step 7, it calls `MakeMethod()`.  If you go to [that part of the specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-makemethod), you will see that's where the `[[HomeObject]]` value gets set.

[image]

So, as you've already discovered `super` relies on `[[HomeObject]]` being set and perusing the specification, this is the only way that it gets set.  So, for `super` to be allowed, it has to call `MakeMethod()` and the only way `MakeMethod()` gets called is with one of the above syntaxes and a regular object literal syntax for a property such as `propName: fn` is not one of them.

Comment: This is so interesting for me if function declared not like method like property have value function which process happened. Which part explain this process in spessification.

Comment: @MuradSofiyev - I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The [[HomeObject]] property is defined on methods of both classes and regular objects. But for objects, methods must be declared exactly as method(), not "method: function()".

There are no differences for us, but they are for JavaScript.

The example below uses the not-method, property-function syntax. So it doesn't have [[HomeObject]], and inheritance doesn't work:

```
 let animal = {
  eat: function(){ 
    console.log(this)
  }
};

let rabbit = {
  __proto__: animal,
  eat: function() {
    super.eat();
  }
};

rabbit.eat();
```

**// Error calling super (because there is no [[HomeObject]])**

as mentioned above

the [[HomeObject]] value is set in the MakeMethod() method, in turn, is only available for functions that fit the role of the method, i.e. functions declared as:

> PropertyName ( StrictFormalParameters ) { FunctionBody }  [that part of the specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-method-definitions)