# What is the difference between a method and a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can someone give a simple explanation of methods vs. functions in Javascript context? I have not found any answer on stack overflow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15285702/4281779

Comment: [What's the difference between a method and a function?](//stackoverflow.com/q/155609)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a practical sense, absolutely nothing. They are the same.

In a semantic sense, a method is simply a function that belongs to an object or class.

This is the same for pretty much every language out there as well. Another term in the same basket is "sub-routine", which is again, pretty much the same exact thing as a function.

Answer (score 1):

I think both are pretty much synonym. However, you might want to use the term `Method` when it is a function within an class/object.

You can read more there:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20909/method-vs-function-vs-procedure