# A really confusing thing about JavaScript methods

Tags: javascript

```js
class Boy {
  sayName = function() {
    console.log('You should rewrite this method!')
  }
  sayName2 = function() {
    return
  }
}

class BabyBoy extends Boy {
  sayName() {
    console.log('I have rewritten this method!')
  }
}

var babyBoy = new BabyBoy()

babyBoy.sayName() // here it outputs: You should rewrite this method!
```

How did it happen?? It's been bugging me for hours!
It seems that there exists some difference between method() and method = function(){}.

Comment: Are you this question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285293/method-vs-functions-and-other-questions

Comment: Check out the difference between `BabyBoy.prototype` and `Boy.prototype`.

Comment: `method(){}` goes to prototype. `method = function(){}` goes to every instance as a property. Member resolution order in javascript first checks if instance has the property, only then goes up the prototype chain. That is why you get property created in parent constructor.

Comment: sayName inherited from Boy is treated as a property so when js tries to execute sayName, it will first check the instance properties. if not found it searches in the instance prototype

Answer (score 1):

Let's "desugar" your code a bit by creating explicit constructor functions (which classes basically are under the hood) and moving public class field definition to the constructor

```js
class Boy {
  constructor() {
    // move public fields to constructor
    this.sayName = function() {
      console.log('You should rewrite this method!')
    }
  }
  
  // define prototype method
  prototypeMethod() {}
}

class BabyBoy extends Boy {
  // add explicit construtor
  constructor() {
    // that calls super
    super()
  }

  sayName() {
    console.log('I have rewritten this method!')
  }

  // override prototype method
  prototypeMethod() {}

}

var babyBoy = new BabyBoy()
var anotherBabyBoy = new BabyBoy()

// lets first ensure that every instance has its own properties
console.log(`babyBoy.sayName === anotherBabyBoy.sayName is ${babyBoy.sayName === anotherBabyBoy.sayName}`)

// check that it doesn't come from prototype
console.log(`babyBoy.sayName === BabyBoy.prototype.sayName is ${babyBoy.sayName === BabyBoy.prototype.sayName}`)

// then make ensure that every instance shares the same method from prototype
console.log(`babyBoy.prototypeMethod === anotherBabyBoy.prototypeMethod is ${babyBoy.prototypeMethod === anotherBabyBoy.prototypeMethod}`)

// check that it comes from prototype
console.log(`babyBoy.prototypeMethod === BabyBoy.prototype.prototypeMethod is ${babyBoy.prototypeMethod === BabyBoy.prototype.prototypeMethod}`)
```